# Sencha Touch: How to prevent button in list item from selecting list item

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.3

I have a list where each item has a "buy" button. The problem is that the click event for the button is passed to the list even if the button's handler returns false. How can I stop the list item from being selected when the button is clicked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `event.stopEvent();` in the button handler. This will call internally `event.stopPropagation();` and `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: And where does the event object come from? I don't see it in the 'handler' function arguments.

Comment: Ah wait, it's not in the examples but it's the second argument passed to the 'handler' config object. Calling stopEvent() worked, thanks!